# Parsing String data from a url using JSON

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, http

what would be the best way to pars this data specifically the value of (TemPreture and HumiDity) with JSON, i have tried several method but no luck

any ideas?

and this is the string in it>>

`{
"id":1174383824,"title":"LED Controler","private":"false","feed":"https://api.xively.com/v2/feeds/1174383824.json","status":"frozen","updated":"2014-01-09T15:33:47.492487Z","created":"2013-10-14T12:17:16.306982Z","creator":"https://xively.com/users/ahmed_soothsayer","version":"1.0.0","datastreams":
[
 {"id":"ALED","current_value":"N","at":"2014-01-09T11:31:15.517313Z","max_value":"0.0","min_value":"0.0"}, {"id":"ALED2","current_value":"N","at":"2014-01-09T11:31:25.343550Z","max_value":"0.0","min_value":"0.0"}, {"id":"ALED3","current_value":"N","at":"2014-01-09T11:31:47.862557Z","max_value":"0.0","min_value":"0.0"}, {"id":"ALED4","current_value":"N","at":"2014-01-09T11:31:37.998191Z","max_value":"0.0","min_value":"0.0"},   {"id":"ALED5","current_value":"P","at":"2014-01-09T15:33:47.264986Z","max_value":"0.0","min_value":"0.0"},   {"id":"HumiDity","current_value":"39.0","at":"2014-01-        09T08:47:17.426770Z","max_value":"3332.2","min_value":"0.0","unit":{"symbol":"%","label":"%"}},    {"id":"HumiDity2","current_value":"61.3","at":"2014-01-        09T08:47:09.933117Z","max_value":"70.2","min_value":"0.0","unit":{"symbol":"%","label":"%"}},   {"id":"Soil_Moisture","current_value":"0","at":"2014-01-        09T08:47:15.428252Z","max_value":"100.0","min_value":"0.0","unit":{"symbol":"%","label":"%"}},   {"id":"Sun_Light","current_value":"17","at":"2014-01-09T08:47:16.459234Z","max_value":"99.9","min_value":"0.0"},   {"id":"TemPreture","current_value":"27","at":"2014-01-09T08:49:19.779376Z","max_value":"66.0","min_value":"-        23.5","unit":{"symbol":"°C","label":"°C"}},{"id":"TemPreture2","current_value":"66.9","at":"2014-01-          09T08:49:35.854478Z","max_value":"66.9","min_value":"-23.4","unit":   {"symbol":"°C","label":"°C"}}],"product_id":"2wQm6WoR-tYxbbyWgBNQ","device_`

Comment: What exactly have you tried?  I prefer to use the [Java JSON library](http://json.org/java/)

Comment: Your example url requires credentials. Please post a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) instead.

Comment: @ChopChop here is the String

Answer (score 0):

You could use Google's Gson to parse. You'll need to download the library and add it to your project. https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/downloads/list

Then you can either parse out the data directly, or create a Java class to match the structure and allow gson to deserialize the string into the Java class.

Primitive deserialization example:

```
int one = gson.fromJson("1", int.class);
```

Object deserialization example:

```
BagOfPrimitives obj = gson.fromJson(jsonString, BagOfPrimitives.class);
```

For full examples, see:
https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Primitives-Examples